# BlendEffect with mask broken on Imaging SDK 3?

Tags: uwp, lumia-imaging-sdk

i'm migrating an app from WP 8.1 to UWP ,so i'm moving to Lumia sdk 3 .
This effect was working fine in SDK 2

> BlendEffect(background, foreground, mask , BlendFunction.Normal , 1f)

but in SDK 3 , the output is only background.

i've tried this

> BlendEffect(background, foreground, BlendFunction.Add)
>   the output is ok

So is the mask broken in sdk 3 ? or the format changed ?

my mask provider is StorageFileImageSource
the image is 32bit BGRA

Comment: if i use the mask as foreground , the output is OK

Comment: Just as a test, can you set RenderOptions.CPU on the Renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24bit BGR  works
nothing documented